# opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory in ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu/linux and opencv, presently working on a image processing project. I am getting the error as following while compiling the code.

main.cpp:1:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"

I installed opencv using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV 
Initially I faced another error "Package OpenCV not found" which i solved by executing 
"export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/opencv.pc"

Now I am stuck with the above problem and do not know how to add the opencv libraries/header files. I found the same problem for visual studio/windows, but could figure out mine. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to provide more information. What is the compilation command you used? Paste a more detailed log from your terminal. Most probably you need to provide an option to the makefile or the compiler to link with the opencv libs.

Comment: There is no such file as core_c.h . It's core.hpp